# Angular Dynamic Components and ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to write a component that could contain different components dynamically. My goal is to be able to write an article where I could either write a paragraph or add a tweet.

This is the code for `DynamicArticleComponent`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-query]'
})
export class QueryDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-article',
  template: 
  `<ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <ng-template dynamic-query></ng-template>
  </ng-container>`,
  styleUrls: ['dynamic-article.component.css']
})
export class DynamicArticleComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() elements: Element[];
    @ViewChildren(QueryDirective) queryDirectives;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.queryDirectives.forEach((queryDirective: QueryDirective, index) => {
        const element = this.elements[index];
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element.component);
        const containerRef = queryDirective.viewContainerRef;
        containerRef.clear();
        const newComponent = containerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<DynamicComponent>newComponent.instance).data = element.data; 
      });
    }
}
```

These are other classes used in the code above:

```
export class Element {
    constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data) {}
}

export interface DynamicComponent {
    data: any;
}
```

I'm having trouble rendering the `<ng-templates>`. It just renders comments and it doesn't change after the view loads. This is what's rendered: [image]

The elements are getting to the component correctly. My idea is to render all the templates, then get them with the ViewChildren decorator, and render the elements where they are supposed to be. Is there other solution to this problem?

Also, this is how the elements reach the `DynamicArticleComponent`:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about it from a design point of view. Make your list of elements be part of a class that implements an interface. aka Decorator Pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, there were two main problems with my code. The first one was pretty dumb. I didn't add the directive to the app module declarations, so it was just like any other html property; angular just didn't expect it, so it didn't look for it. However, after adding it to the app module, it threw `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. This error is caused because I'm changing variables after the view has load. For a more in depth explanation look [this blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4).

In summary, what I did was extracting what I was doing inside the `ngAfterViewInit` into its own function and calling it from a promise. What this does, is creates a microtask queued after the syncronous code has fininshed executing. To learn more about micro and macro tasks in angular, look at this post: [I reverse-engineered Zones (zone.js) and here is what I’ve found](https://blog.angularindepth.com/i-reverse-engineered-zones-zone-js-and-here-is-what-ive-found-1f48dc87659b).

Here is how the code ended up:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-query]'
})
export class QueryDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-article',
  template: 
  `<ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements">
    <ng-template dynamic-query></ng-template>
  </ng-container>`,
  styleUrls: ['dynamic-article.component.css']
})
export class DynamicArticleComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() elements: Element[];
    @ViewChildren(QueryDirective) queryDirectives;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.renderChildren());
    }

    private renderChildren() {
      this.queryDirectives.forEach((queryDirective: QueryDirective, index) => {
        const element = this.elements[index];
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element.component);
        const containerRef = queryDirective.viewContainerRef;
        containerRef.clear();
        const newComponent = containerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (<DynamicComponent>newComponent.instance).data = element.data; 
      });
    }
}
```

This code totally works. Hopefully I help someone.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code with us. I will have study it in order to understand it fully.

Comment: Great solution! I was facing same problem and it is the right way! Thanks!

Comment: If anyone has an explanation as to how this works, please @ me

Comment: @RicardoSaracino javascript works internally with something called an event loop. On the browser, it has to go back and forth between rendering and running your javascript code. When a Promise is created, it gets added into the event loop to run later (when done) and goes back to rendering. If this is not done, the code would be run before rendering. That was the original reason why it was not working.

Comment: You can also do it with `setTimeout`. This will move your code to the end of the call stack and angular can render his initial view first before you are trying to modify it.

Comment: This is brilliant. Works perfectly. How you figured this out, I have no idea--but I'm glad you did. Thank you!

Comment: @JLGradley thank you! Glad it helps. To be honest, I can't even remember how I figured this out. I can only remember the pain :,)